# update table automatically after new post

Tags: ios, objective-c, refresh

I do not know exactly what I need to look, so i ask here.

i created an shoutbox-app for my website. When a user writes a text to the shoutbox the table in the app should be refresh automatically if it is open.

i found this code:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(refreshShoutbox) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

but this code loads every 10 seconds images in the app new. i can see this because there is an activity indicator view every 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but hopefully this helps.

To reload a table, the following code will work:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: yes, but it should only update when a new text was posted in the shoutbox database on the website. Like the facebook app. It updates automatically when someone posted a comment

Answer (score 1):

There are only two solutions for that:

1. Poll a web service periodically in the background and look if a new message was posted. After that reload your table.
2. Use Apple Push Notifications to notify your app that there is something new on the server (this solution may be overhead)